# In matplotlib imshow() how can I change the color axis range on an existing plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When making a plot to start with I can use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
h = ax.imshow(X, vmin=mn, vmax=mx)
```

Once the plot is up, can I change my mind and make `vmin` and `vmax` something different?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the normalization of the image [using `set_norm()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html?highlight=set_norm#matplotlib.image.NonUniformImage.set_norm) and passing a [`Normalize`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) object:

```py
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
h.set_norm(norm)
```

Answer (score 0):

This also does the trick:

```
h.set_clim([mn, mx])
```

And to reset to "auto":

```
h.set_norm(None)
```

Comment: When I read Diziet Asahi's code I immediately understand its intent, when I read yours I don't.  Even if your code is correct it's nonetheless opaque.

Comment: I'm the opposite.  I have no idea what "normalize" is referring to, but coming from matlab, setting the color limits (clim) makes perfect sense.  And it takes only one short line. To each his own.